# click select from the results of an ajax call (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to get some results via a live search script and have the selected choice stay on the input where I typed the query, so far I have this and I do get the list as I'm typing but I've tried different configurations and still havent made it work. This is what I have:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Prueba de asincronía</title>
    <script>
    function showResult(Option) {
      if (Option.length==0) {
        document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
        return;
      }
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=this.responseText;
          document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","estados.php?busca_edo="+Option,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
      </head>
      <body>
    <form>
    <input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)" value="">
    <div id="livesearch"></div>
    </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

And the mysqli query looks like this:

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    include("db_connetion.php");

    $states_search = $_GET['busca_edo'];
    $q4=mysqli_query($cnx,"SELECT * FROM estados WHERE estado LIKE '%$states_search%' ORDER BY estado ASC");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($q4) >= 1){

    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q4)){
    ?>

    <option value="<?= $rows['id'] ?>"><?= $rows['estado'] ?></option>

    <?php
    }
    }else{
    echo '<option value="">No hay resultados</option>';
    }
    ?>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction and please no JQuery?

Thanks You all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just re-writing the while loop , place it in your code and you will get the exact result .

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($q4) >= 1){
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($q4, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "<option value='".$rows['id']."'>".$rows['estado']."</option>" ;
    }
}
else{
    echo '<option value="">No hay resultados</option>';
}
```

Comment: Thank You PHP Web, but it gives the same result. What I need is to be able to click on any of the elements that I get back and make it fill the same input field. I tried using javascript (and of course its not working for I'm not good at javascript) 
If let's say I get 3 lines back from the ajax call, Campeche | Chiapas | Chihuahua and I click on Chiapas, let that be the ending value for the input. So the way I figure, It's more a JavaScript thing.